# crash due to SocialAuth Library project

Tags: android, crash, android-logcat, socialauth

I m facing problem while adding social auth library project (of google).

there are two jar files used socialauth-2.3 and socialauth-android

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.fbLogin:
        adapter = new SocialAuthAdapter(new ResponseListener()); //<----- after this it crashes
        wmbPreference = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        boolean isFirstRun = wmbPreference.getBoolean("FIRSTRUN", true);
        adapter.authorize(LoginActivity.this, Provider.FACEBOOK);
        adapter.addProvider(Provider.FACEBOOK, R.drawable.apppurchase);
        break;

    case R.id.loginWithExistingAccount:
        new SignInDialog(context, typeface);
        break;
    case R.id.createNewAccount:
        new SignUpDialog(context, typeface, imeiString);
        break;

    default:
        break;
    }

}
```

Below is my logcat

```
07-15 12:05:20.498: E/AndroidRuntime(1353): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-15 12:05:20.498: E/AndroidRuntime(1353): Process: com.example.puzzleapplication, PID: 1353
07-15 12:05:20.498: E/AndroidRuntime(1353): android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x0
07-15 12:05:20.498: E/AndroidRuntime(1353):     at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1123)
07-15 12:05:20.498: E/AndroidRuntime(1353):     at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:698)
07-15 12:05:20.498: E/AndroidRuntime(1353):     at org.brickred.socialauth.android.SocialAuthDialog.setUpTitle(SocialAuthDialog.java:181)
07-15 12:05:20.498: E/AndroidRuntime(1353):     at org.brickred.socialauth.android.SocialAuthDialog.onCreate(SocialAuthDialog.java:143)
07-15 12:05:20.498: E/AndroidRuntime(1353):     at android.app.Dialog.dispatchOnCreate(Dialog.java:361)
07-15 12:05:20.498: E/AndroidRuntime(1353):     at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:262)
07-15 12:05:20.498: E/AndroidRuntime(1353):     at org.brickred.socialauth.android.SocialAuthAdapter$3$1.run(SocialAuthAdapter.java:418)
07-15 12:05:20.498: E/AndroidRuntime(1353):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
07-15 12:05:20.498: E/AndroidRuntime(1353):     at     android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
07-15 12:05:20.498: E/AndroidRuntime(1353):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
07-15 12:05:20.498: E/AndroidRuntime(1353):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
07-15 12:05:20.498: E/AndroidRuntime(1353):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-15 12:05:20.498: E/AndroidRuntime(1353):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
07-15 12:05:20.498: E/AndroidRuntime(1353):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
07-15 12:05:20.498: E/AndroidRuntime(1353):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
07-15 12:05:20.498: E/AndroidRuntime(1353):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Can u guys help me to tract it out

Regards

Comment: Are you setting int to textview somewhere?

Comment: better to post your code...

Comment: @MD pls check i have now posted my code block also

Comment: @Mann check your Library is not properly configure....

Comment: I m using 'socialauth-2.3.jar' and 'socialauth-android.jar' and its looking to be just fine.

Comment: @Mann post `SocialAuthAdapter` and indiacate line 181 in the same

Comment: its all inside the jar file :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to put the name of the drawable like in the sample project:

Put:

```
adapter.addProvider(Provider.FACEBOOK, R.drawable.facebook);
```

instead of:

```
adapter.addProvider(Provider.FACEBOOK, R.drawable.apppurchase);
```

And them it will work.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i am concert this is an error of your resource. 
1.you are not properly getting view on which you are trying to set drawable that might causing 
the error in next line that could be related to social auth 
2.recheck your **findViewbyid's first**.